# Are there ways on knowing/predecting how long/many are the delay/attempts of Duplicate Address Detection?

Tags: ipv6

Hi guys need help on my project, I was stuck on this research where I am looking for knowing how long is a usual DAD.

I'm looking thru the RFC and what I got is that it has a "Random Delay" but there are no information on that matter.

At most the prediction does not need to be 100% accurate, I need this so I can make a counter based approach on stopping the attack of DoS on DAD. My system counts the delay time and how many attempts are made then if it sees it pass the abnormal state it will mitigate the problem.

Thanks for sharing your answers and thougts about this

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The interval between DAD attempts depends on implementation and configuration. Cisco's default is 1 second (1000ms) but that can be configured to be anything between 1000ms and 3600000ms with the `ipv6 nd dad time` command.

See http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/ipv6/command/reference/ipv6_book/ipv6_07.html#wp2359130

Comment: Oh, Is that so. how about a  failed attempt? I look at a .cap file that goes around .9 - 1 sec the successful DAD.
Do not have any information for failed ones.  
and 
How can I know if there is a abnormal attempts happening? Like in span of 1 second how can I say the DAD Attempts are abnormal